# How to get rid of 'No main class detected!' error?

Tags: sbt

SBT shows me the error `No main class detected!` for utility project which is not meant to be started. It just used as dependency.

**How do I tell it not to bother?**

`sbt sbtVersion` yields `0.3.11`

`brew list sbt` yields `1.0.2`

Comment: Could you add your build.sbt file to your question?

Comment: Could you also add a log of your session, including what command(s) you ran, and exactly what sbt outputted?